# Create a copy memfd_create

Tags: linux, filesystems, fork, in-memory

I'm using `memfd_create` to keep a file in memory but when I `fork` this file is shared between the 2 process.

Is it possible to decouple the parent and the child in such a way that the child will have an in-memory copy of the file, after the fork? Such as when the child alters the file, the parent process is not affected.

If not, what other options do I have to keep a file in memory (while still using read/write/seek operations) and create copies on fork?

Comment: The FD returned by this acts just like an ordinary file. If you open a regular file and fork, both processes see all the changes to the file.

Comment: @Barmar Yea! Is there a way to decouple the parent and the child and each one having a private copy of the file? I was hopping as `memfd_create` is in memory, that private mapping would be possible.

Comment: It's not in your process's memory, it's in system memory, like `tmpfs`. The documentation is clear: **With respect to fork(2) and execve(2), the usual semantics apply for
       the file descriptor created by memfd_create().  A copy of the file
       descriptor is inherited by the child produced by fork(2) and refers
       to the same file.**

Comment: Do you need an FD, or can you settle for a `FILE *` without one like `fmemopen` or `open_memstream` give?

Answer (score 0):

I hope not to be wrong here but in the child, `mmap` the `memfd_file` using `MAP_PRIVATE` as flag and then `fclose` the inherited `fd`. That way the child will have its own private copy (on-write) of the contents of the file.

If you want the child to have its own copy of the file without adding more virtual memory to the child, I think you have no other choice but to make the parent create, before the `fork`, a new memfd for the child beforehand, copy the contents of the parent's memfd to the child's memfd, then `fork`, and finally make the child `fclose` the parent's `memfd`, and the parent close the child's `memfd`.

For simplicity, if you use the strategy of making the parent replicate the file for the child, to remove the `close` on the child, when creating the parent's `memfd`, use the `MFD_CLOEXEC` flag so that the parent's `memfd` is not inherited in the first place.

In other words, make the parent create the copy